# how to make a py file to exe with pyinstaller when the py file dynamically creates and names data files and reads them after running starts?

Tags: python, windows, exe, executable, pyinstaller

I know how to help pyinstaller to catch data files with .spec file but It is only when the names of them are fixed before executing pyinstaller. Anyone knows how to make the py file to exe that dinamically creates and names data files(.txt) and reads them on running? If It is impossible with pyinstaller, is there any other recommended tools?

I tried on windows10 and windows7 with python version 3.6 and 3.7.

Comment: The `.spec` file is actually a 'regular' python code file that pyinstaller will execute. You can insert your own python code into the `.spec` file. So you can add some code that creates a list of the data file names and then pass it to the `datas` argument of `Analysis`.

Comment: I do not get the problem. It does not matter if a Python script creates and reads files or if an executable does so. I think you should share at least some pseudo code.